# IS !value a shortcut for IS NOT NULL MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, null, shorthand

When playing with MySQL I noticed that if I run

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE !value;
```

returns the same thing as

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value IS NOT NULL;
```

The table is "employees" and the column is "MiddleInitial" (strings).
So I get all employees who's MiddleInitial is not null.

Is this a proper shorthand or just a coincidence? I am wondering if this is a safe way to write? I cannot seem to find any information on this.

I was expecting

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE !value;
```

to return all null values. Oddly enough

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value;
```

returns nothing.

Comment: Column value data type?

Comment: ...and sample data?

Comment: `!FALSE` returns 1, `!TRUE` returns 0, i.e. works as `NOT`. And `!0` returns 1, and `!1` returns 0.

Comment: _The !, operator is a nonstandard MySQL extension. As of MySQL 8.0.17, this operator is deprecated; expect it to be removed in a future version of MySQL. Applications should be adjusted to use the standard SQL NOT operator._

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not.

It might seem like it because it's doing type coercion to force whatever is in the column into a boolean value. `NULL` values will coerce to `false` when forced as a [boolean predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)), and **most** non-null column values will coerce to `true`. But **some** column values (that are not null) will also coerce to `false`.

You can see examples here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/ABLUgLex

Notice the last example is missing the `0` row. Also notice the one before that does not include the `null` row, which leads me to suspect your server might have an option set for non-standard null handling.

Here's a few more samples:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/BNxiujKt

Notice the treatment of the `'1'` row.

Comment: Argh, I'd missed updating the link after the last test. This is fixed now so it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, `NULL` is not the same as `false`.

Negating `NULL` is not `true`, it's still `NULL`.

```
mysql> select null;
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+

mysql> select !(null);
+---------+
| !(null) |
+---------+
|    NULL |
+---------+
```

Think of `NULL` as the value "unknown." If some piece of information is unknown, how can its opposite be known? It can't — the opposite is also unknown, because we don't know what we started with.

When used in a `WHERE` clause condition, `NULL` acts more or less like `false` because neither are strictly `true`. Only rows where the conditions are `true` become part of the result set of the query.

There are other values that act like `false` in MySQL:

```
mysql> select 1 where '';
Empty set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select 1 where 0;
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

MySQL is a bit nonstandard because the boolean values `true` and `false` are literally the same as the integer values 1 and 0 respectively (this is not the way booleans are implemented in most other brands of SQL database).

These values are not `NULL`, so they can be negated and you can treat their opposites as `true`.

```
mysql> select 1 where !0;
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+

mysql> select 1 where !'';
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
```

As the comment above said, the `!` operator is deprecated in MySQL 8.0. It's not standard SQL, and using it makes your code less clear than if you use more explicit language like `IS NOT NULL` or `<>`.